# Access JSON Object Prop - Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs, http, get

First time using Angular JS, I'm using $http.get to return a Json object. When I output the response data, I can see entire JSON object in the console, but I can't access the object or properties. What am I missing here?

```
    $scope.init = function (value) {
        $scope.productEditorModel.productId = value;
        $scope.loadData($scope.productEditorModel.productId);
    }

    $scope.loadData = function (productId) {
        var responsePromise = $http.get("/Product/GetProductModel", {
            params: { productId: productId }
        });

        responsePromise.success(function (dataFromServer, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(dataFromServer.DataModel);

          });
    };
```

When I first output the dataFromServer to the console,  the object is null and then it becomes populated. Since it's an async call, I should be able to access and set whatever vars inside the success

I would like to be able to directly access the object and property names IE:

```
    $scope.productModel.productId = dataFromServer.Data.productId
```

My json looks like this:

```
  Object{DataModel:Object, IsSuccess: false}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is it logging out?

Comment: I'm getting this back when I log the dataFromServer......Object{DataModel:Object, IsSuccess: false}

Post is updated

Comment: And what if you log dataFromServer.DataModel?

Comment: First time I log dataFromServer.DataModel it is null, second time it is an object with props like this:

Object{ProductId:1,Title:"Product Name"} etc...but when I try to access a prop by name for example dataFromServer.DataModel.Title, I get this error: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to access it?  You have to wait until the data is populated before you try to access it because otherwise there is nothing but a promise object there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the data before it comes back.  Here is a plunker that demonstrates how to set it up, and how not to.

```
  //predefine our object that we want to stick our data into
  $scope.myDataObject = {
    productId: 'nothing yet',
    name: 'nothing yet'
  }

  //get the data, and when we have it, assign it to our object, then the DOM will automatically update
  $http.get('test.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.myDataObject = data
  });

  var y = $http.get('test.json')
  //this throws an error because I am trying to access the productId property of the promise object, which doesn't exist.
  console.log(y.productId);
```

Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lCRAgIVaJq0Wm4q4H1KF?p=preview)

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks! I didn't realize I had to mock up an empty data object to bind to.

Comment: well...you don't HAVE to...but it won't behave very nicely.

Comment: Makes good sense :)

I made this plunker using the empty data object, but I'm still getting that undefined error, what I am missing, gotta be something stupid

http://plnkr.co/edit/zlUsTHcjFV6sOWvPFlVK?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/G922Eda7Z9nxZVDsca4A?p=preview

A few things - you don't need that Array prefix.  Format your json correctly (no semi-colons in a json file).
The primary issue though was you weren't accessing your data at the right property.
Wrap your returned json data in `angular.json(dataFromServer)`, but it has to be purely JSON or it will throw an error (you should probably run this through a try/catch block)

Comment: Perfect thanks, after adding the try/catch, the undefined error went away. I did reformat the JSON as suggested, but the JSON object still comes back as undefined the first time around...so the try catch handles it well.